# Trouble installing Choroplethr for R version 3.5.0

Tags: r, installation, choroplethr

I'm not able to install the Choroplethr package.

I've installed the 'devtools' package and the GitHub repo

```
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0').
```

When I run zip_choropleth() I get error: 'could not find function "zip_choropleth"'.

I tried installing the 'choroplethrZip' package and get error:  ‘choroplethrZip’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)'.

I'm not sure what else to do or if it is simply not available for my version of R.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
install.packages('devtools')
library('devtools')
install.packages('choroplethrZip')
library('choroplethrZip')
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')
zip_choropleth(df,..)
```

Error:...package ‘choroplethrZip’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)

Comment: Have you tried loading the package after you install it using devtools?

Comment: yes, if you mean library('devtools')

Comment: No they meant `library(choroplethrZip)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have the `devtools` package installed. So this is probably the code that you need:

```
# install choroplethrZip
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')

# load choroplethrZip
library(choroplethrZip)

# create an example map
data(df_pop_zip)
zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip, state_zoom = "new york")
```

[image: NY ZCTA map]

The key point is this: `choroplethrZip` is not on CRAN. So typing `install.packages("choroplethrZip")` will never work.